# Functional equation in $x,y$: $f(x)f(y)=f\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)f\left(\frac{a}{y}\right)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Let $f:(0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ and $a>0$ such that $f(a)=1$. Prove that, if
\begin{align*}
f(x)f(y)=f\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)f\left(\frac{a}{y}\right),\quad\forall x,y>0
\end{align*}
then $f$ is constant.

Comment: If $f$ is constant then $f(x)=1$ and not any arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false. The function $$f(x)=\left|\ln x\right|$$ has the property with $a=1$, but it is not constant.

Comment: $f(a)=0$ in this case

Comment: but $\ln 1=0$ not $1$

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen:  It is easy to deduce that $f(1)$ must be equal to $1$. In your example $f(1)=0$

Answer (score 1):

$$
f_1(x)=\begin{cases}
x & \mathbf{if}\;\;x\in(0;1]\\
1/x & \mathbf{if}\;\;x\in(1;+\infty)
\end{cases},
\qquad
f_2(x)=\begin{cases}
1/x & \mathbf{if}\;\;x\in(0;1]\\
x & \mathbf{if}\;\;x\in(1;+\infty)
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: You say "If $f(1)=0...$". If you put $x=y=a$ in the initial condition, then you get immediately that $f(a)^2=f(1)^2$ so that $f(1)=\pm1$ only. Hence, you can exclude this case from your solution.

Comment: I only got $f(a)=f \left( \frac{1}{a} \right)=f(a^2)=f \left( \frac{1}{a^2} \right)=...=f(a^n)=f \left( \frac{1}{a^n} \right) =1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z_+}$

Answer (score 1):

You have $(f(a))^2=(f(1))^2\Rightarrow f(1)=1$ ($f$ is a function so we discard $f(1)=-1$).

It follows for all $y>0$, $$f(y)=f(\frac ay)$$
Making $a=1$ you have $$f(y)=f(\frac 1y)$$

This is verified by the function $$f(y)=\frac 12(y+\frac 1y)$$ which is not constant.

**The claim is false.**

EDITION.-My son tells me that for any positive a, the function 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{|\ln a|}\left(|\ln \frac xa|+|\ln x|\right)$$ is a counterexample. **This is much better than $a=1$**